# org.web3j.protocol.exceptions.ClientConnectionException: Invalid response received: 403; error code: 1020

Tags: web3j, java

I have very simple java code using web3j library. I am using mumbai test network for polygon. After calling
`String chainId = web3j.netVersion().send().getNetVersion();` line I get error that is written in title. This exact line was working fine in my spring boot application several days ago, but now it causes same error message.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String networkPoly = "https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com/";
        Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService(networkPoly));
        String chainId = web3j.netVersion().send().getNetVersion();
        System.out.println(chainId);

    }
}
```

I use example from official documentation: http://docs.web3j.io/4.8.7/smart_contracts/interacting_with_smart_contract/

I use Web3j version - 3.8.7

What is causing this and how can I get chainId without this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic [HTTP code](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) that indicates that the server understood your request, but refused to execute it.

Compare your spring boot application with this one to check if there is something changed and/or contact the server administrator to check if there has been some changes.

Comment: rpc interface was not working, so changing rpc interface solved the issue. Thank you